# How to integrate both authorization with OAuth and authentication with Devise in one step?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, oauth, devise

I managed to get authorization working following this tutorial and oauth-plugin: http://unhandledexpression.com/2011/06/02/rails-and-oauth-plugin-part-1-the-provider/

However, in a mobile app context, I'm stuck in how to make both authorization and authentication (with Devise) in one step - since the user already logged in to get the oauth access token.

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :oauth_required

  def current_user=(user)
      current_user = user
  end

  def show_current_user
      puts current_user ### nil
  end
end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

So your question is, why current_user is nil? Or do you have a question like the following? [OAuth2 Provider: How to offer a login page in order to let oauth clients get the resource owner id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101720/oauth2-provider-how-to-offer-a-login-page-in-order-to-let-oauth-clients-get-the)

Instead of before_filter you should use the (yet undocumented) *oauthenticate* method.

class ApiController < ApplicationController

oauthenticate

end