# OAuth2 Provider: How to offer a login page in order to let oauth clients get the resource owner id

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails-3, rest, mobile, oauth-2.0

I'm developing a RESTful API in Rails3 and a corresponding OAuth2 provider (consumed by android clients).

I supply the typical routes:

authorize =>  Authorization Grant

token => receive access_token

All this is working and my mobile clients receive and save the access tokens for the resource owners.

But now, how do I inform the mobile client about who is currently using the app and which access_token it has to use from the database?

I need a login page and then perhaps send the user's id to an app's callback URL? Is there a standard process for this? What kind of login page mobile clients can handle best?

Answer (score 0):

OK obviously you don't care about authenticating the user on smartphones.
At least one should offer and API resource to invalidate an access_token (Logout via App).